# Convert a Week format like 201729 in a dataframe to a month in a new column where the date is the first monday

Tags: python, pandas

I found this but cant get the syntax correct.

```
time.asctime(time.strptime('2017 28 1', '%Y %W %w'))
```

I want to set a new column to show month in the format "201707" for July. It can be int64 or string doesnt have to be an actual readable date in the column.

My dataframe column ['Week'] is also in the format 201729 i.e. YYYYWW

```
 dfAttrition_Billings_KPIs['Day_1'] = \
  time.asctime(time.strptime(dfAttrition_Billings_KPIs['Week'].str[:4] 
     + dfAttrition_Billings_KPIs['Month'].str[:-2] - 1 + 1', '%Y %W %w'))
```

So I want the output of the rows that have week 201729 to show in a new field month 201707. the output depends on what the row value is in 'Week'.

I have a million records so would like to avoid iterations of rows, lambdas and slow functions where possible :)

Comment: This is very unclear. Please post some actual data we can work with. You're forcing us to take shots in the dark.

Comment: My bad, I was trying to rush the question out there before I went home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format` with add `1` for `Mondays`, last for format `YYYYMM` use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[201729,201730,201735]})

df['date1']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + '1', format='%Y%W%w')
df['date2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + '1', format='%Y%W%w').dt.strftime('%Y%m')
print (df)
     date      date1   date2
0  201729 2017-07-17  201707
1  201730 2017-07-24  201707
2  201735 2017-08-28  201708
```

If need convert from datetime to `weeks` custom format:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=10)})

df['date3'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y %W %w')
print (df)
        date      date3
0 2017-01-01  2017 00 0
1 2017-01-02  2017 01 1
2 2017-01-03  2017 01 2
3 2017-01-04  2017 01 3
4 2017-01-05  2017 01 4
5 2017-01-06  2017 01 5
6 2017-01-07  2017 01 6
7 2017-01-08  2017 01 0
8 2017-01-09  2017 02 1
9 2017-01-10  2017 02 2
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael That will definitely work for my purposes. I guess the only technical issue I could face is I ideally I need the ISO week beginning Monday. As this seems to be Sunday to Saturday with a selection of the Monday. Technically the weeks are one day miss-aligned. For my current task this would be an unnoticeable issue so thanks a lot for your excellent answer it works a treat.